# Purpose of Beis Hamikdash

Tags: tefilla, rambam, beis-hamikdash, korban, parashat-teruma

Rambam writes that the purpose of the beis hamikdash is specifically for offering sacrifices and for pilgrimages (Sefer Hamitzvos: Shoresh 12):

> שיהיה לנו בית מוכן יבאו אליו ויחוגי בו ובו תהיה ההקרבה ובו יהיה הקבוץ במועדים

He implies as much elsewhere as well (sefer Hamitzvos pos. 20 (with a slight twist), Hil. Beis Hab'chira 1:1)

Two question:

A) What is his source that these particular purposes are the primary purposes for which we are commanded to build it?

B) Why doesn't he mention it as a place of prayer as God refers the (future) beis hamikdash as a place of prayer (Isaiah 56:7)

> כִּי בֵיתִי בֵּית תְּפִלָּה יִקָּרֵא לְכָל הָעַמִּים

---

Please cite sources.

Comment: Regarding B at least, that's a quote taken out of context. The full quote makes clear that this is a future messianic event. When "I will bring them to my Holy Mountain (Jerusalem)" is when the Beis Hamikdash will be **transformed** into a "place of prayer for **all the nations."** Also, keep in mind that the Rambam's definition of prayer involves more than just what we typically label as such. And for A, the commandment is to have a mishkan/mikdash to fulfill the connected korbanot. I think you're mixing things up here...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky you are right. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: For the latter point, I think that mentioning how ***other people/nations*** will use the Beis Hamikdash in the future is outside the scope of what he's trying to accomplish - namely a clear and clean description of halacha. Rambam states ***what we must do,*** irrespective of how other people will or won't act. Whether people from other nations come to pray in the Beis Hamikdash is immaterial to our obligations there.